# Hacking attempts? Or what could it be?

Tags: php, apache, http, post, get

I ran into a problem in General.
Already that day I have been observing the following:

> AH00126: Invalid URI in request HEAD /icons/.%2e/%2e%2e/apache2/icons/sphere1.png HTTP/1.1

> AH01630: Invalid URI in request POST /cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh HTTP/1.1

> AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET /cgi-bin/.%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/etc/passwd HTTP/1.1

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/*****/html/

What is it anyway?
How to deal with this!?
Costs: `Apache/2.4.6`

Nothing broke, but it clogs the logs, in errors, tried to ban IPs, but change at the speed of light.

Please help to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
There were old settings from the previous version.

It seems that it does not appear anymore, maybe someone will need to leave it here.

All problems are solved right here.
Here is one of them:
[ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration)

Everything else is by analogy.